# How to return a column value (record ID) from a nested form record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form in a Rails 3.1 app, using Cocoon gem.

In the child form, I have a link that, when clicked, should return the id of the child and pass it to a javascript function.

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
    parent fields...
    <%= f.fields_for :child  do |child| %>
    <%= link "run function", 'string-to-pass' => "#{child.id}" %>   
    child fields...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What is the correct syntax to return a column variable from a nested record?

`child.id` returns `undefined local variable or method "child"`

I could define an @child variable in the parent controller, but how do I point it towards the child ID, rather than the parent ID?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't see how this fits together?

Grateful for any suggestions or pointers to relevant information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like: `child.object.id`

I haven't tested it so please let me know if it works.

EDIT:
I have code like this in my view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :children do |child| %>
  <%= render "child_fields", :f => child %>
<% end %>
```

And then in `_child_fields.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.object.some_attribute %>
 and other view stuff
```

And this works.

Can you try adapting your code to be similar. One thing I just realized, in your fields_for you need to say:

```
<%= f.fields_for :children
```

rather than:

```
<%= f.fields_for :child
```

Assuming, of course that you have a one-to-many relation going on here.

Comment: thanks @adnan. That still returns `undefined local variable or method "child"`

Comment: Gosh now I feel stupid. I had completely forgotten/ overlooked the mapping of :f => child. Doh! Yes `f.object.attribute` now works perfectly. Thank you, thank you, thank you. (the pluralization of child in the fields_for was simply a mistake in writing the question, the actual form is set up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand why you're talking about @variables in the controller if you want to call a javascript function, but anyway...
I think you're looking for the helper *link_to_function* with some code like:

`link_to_function('link', "myJSFunction(#{child.id});"`

Is that your problem?

Comment: thanks Aledalgrande, appreciate your help but no that is not my problem. I'm not having any difficulties with the javascript, and don't need to call a javascript, but need to have child.id available to use elsewhere. My problem is that I can't return a value for child.id. Perhaps I am not understanding how nested-forms work. Using the syntax above - child.id - I get `undefined local variable or method "child"`